# Mongo - Return items that exist with one value but not another

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents that represent products available in different locales. Some products are available only in certain locales. If a product isn't specifically listed for a given locale, then it's not available for that locale.

Here's a tiny example, with only the pertinent bits:

```
{ "locale": "US", "productId": "123" }
{ "locale": "CA", "productId": "123" }
{ "locale": "FR", "productId": "123" }
{ "locale": "US", "productId": "456" }
{ "locale": "FR", "productId": "456" }
```

I'd like to query for all the productIds that are available in the US, but not in CA. In this example, that'd be productId 456.

If I were doing this in SQL, I'd join the table to itself and find the answer that way. But I'm not sure how to tackle this sort of query in Mongo. What's the most appropriate way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline:

```
db.products.aggregate([ 
  { $group: { _id: "$productId", locales: { $push: "$locale" } } },
  { $match: { locales: "US", locales: {$nin: ["CA"] } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, productId: "$_id" } }
])
```

Details:

1. Group products by id and push all product locales into the array.
2. Select those documents which have US locale but don't have CA locale
3. Project results to get only productId values.

Output:

```
{ "productId" : "456" }
```

---

Note that you can get all product ids in single array if you'll do grouping after match stage:

```
{ $group: { _id: 1, productIds: { $push: "$_id" } } }
```

Comment: maybe there is a way also with $lookup using `locale` as localField and foreignField, what's do you think?

Comment: @alfredopacino I don't think we need lookup here, because OP asks for product ids - grouping fits perfectly for this task

Answer (score 1):

According to description as mentioned in above question please try executing following aggregate query in MongoDB shell.

```
    db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
             _id:{productId:'$productId'},
             locale:{$addToSet:'$locale'}
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $match: {
               locale:{$in:['US'],$nin:['CA']}
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

The above mentioned aggregate query executes following stages of aggregation in pipeline.

- $group operator groups documents according to values of productId and
  push values of locale associated to productId into an array using
  $addToSet operator.
- $match operator filters documents having only US locale along
  with excluding documents having CA locale from array of locale
  values generated in group stage.